# Аggregation of the result in different years in a new column.Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

```
Тhis is the result i achieved on a monthly basis.
```

Here I collected all the results on a monthly basis In Comulative.
Еach new period is added to the old periods in a cumulative

SELECT date,period,SUM(period)  OVER(ORDER BY date  ) AS Comulative)
group by date

```
date,        period     cumulative  
1-May-19,      1,      1    
1-Jun-19,      2,      3    
1-Jul-19,      4,      7    
1-Aug-19,      1,      8    
1-Sep-19,      0,      8    
1-May-20,      10,     18   
1-Feb-20,      0,     18    
1-Mar-20,      0,     18    
1-Apr-21,      1,     19    
1-Jul-21,      1,     20    
1-Aug-21,      1,     21    
1-Sep-21,      1,     22
```

I want to achieve the same result  on an annual basis.

```
date,         period, cumolative 
2019,            8,     8
2020,            10,     18
2021,             4,     22
```

I use this to format the date.
to_char(date,'yyyy')

Comment: UNTESTED But something like `Sum(Period) over (partition by Year(date) order by date) as Cumulative_Year`  Just continue with your analytic/window functions  or `Extract(YEAR from Date)` instead of `Year(Date)` depending on your preference and versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first generate the SUM result and then can do a cumulative sum -

```
SELECT date, period, SUM(period) OVER(ORDER BY date)
  FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) date, SUM(period) period
          FROM YOUR_TABLE
         GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date));
```

Comment: how would it be obtained if the result of a period is formed by 2 columns
input - output = Period
I tried many options but it didn't work

Comment: Please ask a new question for a new problem with sample data and expected result.